# Laptop freezes unexpectedly

Tags: 14.04, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo T540p laptop with ubuntu 14.04. I have been using it for about 2 weeks and it froze 4 times (3 times with dark screens and 1 time with the same screen I was working with)
After rebooting I was able to find some errors in the kern.log file (was able to find it in the last time).

These are the last log entries in /var/log/kern.log before the laptop froze.

```
May 23 22:12:11 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44393.522662] ata1: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen
May 23 22:12:11 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44393.522672] ata1: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
May 23 22:12:11 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44393.522679] ata1: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
May 23 22:12:11 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44393.522687] ata1: hard resetting link
May 23 22:12:11 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44393.522710] ata6: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen
May 23 22:12:11 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44393.522718] ata6: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
May 23 22:12:11 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44393.522724] ata6: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
May 23 22:12:11 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44393.522733] ata6: hard resetting link
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.246738] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.246783] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.247101] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.247103] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.247417] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.248112] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.248115] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.248284] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.248537] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.250996] ata6.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:1f:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.252530] ata6.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:02:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.262170] ata6.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:1f:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.262712] ata1: EH complete
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.263819] ata6.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:02:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.266965] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 23 22:12:12 maduranga-ThinkPad-T540p kernel: [44394.282767] ata6: EH complete
```

Can anyone suggest me what might be the problem? Hardware issue or a software issue?

Edit: the output of `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2` as suggested.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2210
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of "lspci -l | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2" terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have added the data you requested

Comment: Have you found a solution for it?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No I couldn't find the solution and didn't had the problem for the past few days

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly the same problem with my T540p on Ubuntu 14.04 for the past two months and It's been a week that I (manually) upgraded the kernel to (the official) [4.1.3](https://www.kernel.org/) and eventually the problem is gone. Previously, I was using 3.19.x.  I guess, that's because newer (> 4.0.0 version) kernels have better support for Realtek wireless cards!